# Bring information from 2 tables and put it in the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table of articles

```
---------------------------------------------
|   Article   |   Location    | existence   | 
---------------------------------------------
|     200116    |   cc3111      |   1       |
---------------------------------------------
|     200116    |   ee3091      |       1   |
---------------------------------------------
```

And this count table

```
----------------------------------------------------
|   Article   |   Location     |   Quantity      |
----------------------------------------------------
|     200116    |   cc3111       |   10            |
----------------------------------------------------
|     200116    |   EE3091       |   8             |
----------------------------------------------------
|     200116    |   EE2102       |   5             |
----------------------------------------------------
|     200116    |   DD5131       |   7             |
----------------------------------------------------
```

What I'm trying to do is give me one result like the next.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Article   |   Location    | Existence      |  Quantity |   DIF      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     200116  |   CC3111      |     1          |     10    |     9       |     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     200116  |   EE3091      |     1          |     8     |      7      | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     200116  |   DD5131      |     0          |    7      |     7       |  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     200116  |   EE2102      |     0          |    5      |     5      |   
----------------------------- -------------------------------------------
```

But without doing it with a `Union` since then I have to make another query, I just do not know how to join it without using`Union`.

-SOME HELP TO PERFORM THIS QUERY

-I do not know how to add the location in the same column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another option...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Article', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Article;

CREATE TABLE #Article (
    Article INT NOT NULL,
    Location CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    Existance INT NOT NULL 
    );

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Counts', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Counts;

CREATE TABLE #Counts (
    Article INT NOT NULL,
    Location CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    Quantity INT NOT NULL 
    );

INSERT #Article(Article, Location, Existance) VALUES
    (200116, 'cc3111', 1), (200116, 'ee3091', 1);

INSERT #Counts(Article, Location, Quantity) VALUES
    (200116, 'cc3111', 10), (200116, 'EE3091', 8),
    (200116, 'EE2102', 5), (200116, 'DD5131', 10);

SELECT * FROM #Article a;
SELECT * FROM #Counts c;

--=====================================================

SELECT 
    Article = COALESCE(a.Article, c.Article),
    Location = COALESCE(a.Location, c.Location),
    Existance = COALESCE(a.Existance, 0),
    Quantity = COALESCE(c.Quantity, 0),
    DIF =  COALESCE(c.Quantity, 0) - COALESCE(a.Existance, 0)
FROM
    #Article a
    FULL JOIN #Counts c
        ON a.Article = c.Article
        AND a.Location = c.Location;
```

Comment: If I put a `WHERE a.Article = 200116`; it no longer works

Comment: Adding that to a WHERE clause filters out the a.Article = NULLs that result from the FULL JOIN. Remove it from the WHERE clause and add it to the FULL JOIN ON clause...

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a `left join`:

```
select t2.*, coalesce(t1.existence, 0) as existence,
       (t2.quantity - coalesce(t1.existence, 0)) as dif
from t2 left join
     t1
     on t2.article = t1.article and t2.location = t1.location;
```

Comment: And how to add the `articles`, I do not know how to put them in the same column

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  This should give the result set in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **JOIN** these tables instead of doing a **UNION**. The former will put columns side by side, whereas the latter will stack two similar sources together...